# Any php script to convert an 2D image to 3D?

Tags: php, 3d

I generate a stereo anaglyph image from two source images (left.jpg and right.jpg) follow the tutorial of this site: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3325-PHP-Generate-a-stereo-image-from-two-source-images.html#files

This tutorial need to use 2 source images to create 3d, any php script can create 3d image from only one source image?  Or any php script can convert an 2D image to 2 images (left, right)?

Answer (score 4):

Depth is perceived through *both* eyes, not one. Cover one eye and throw something. It will feel really odd, as your brain has trouble calculating distances without depth.

The depth is calculated (at least on computers) by looking at differences between the left and right images (which is why your eyes are spaced apart, to give differences).

The only reason you can "see" a stereograph is because you are simulating the act of looking through both eyes with one combined image.

You need two.

Comment: Detecting scene geometry is pretty complex, though. Try piping [this](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/images/optical_illusion_cube.png) into that software and look at the output. Using two images would do away with any ambiguity in that case.

Comment: i have to do a task with upload an image then generate a 3d images by click a button. I don't have the left and right image that need to create the 3d. I think the left and right image need to adjust in some specific angle to make the 3d image. Any script can generate the left and right image from an image?

Comment: Did you read my answer? You ***cannot*** recreate a 3D image from a 2D image. You don't have enough information. It's like asking "what numbers add up to 5"? There are *infinitely* many answers.